# CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '+@MANV+'

Tags: sql-server

```
    CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_INS_PUBLIC_NHANVIEN](@MANV varchar(20), @HOTEN nvarchar(100), @EMAIL varchar(20), @LUONGCB nvarchar(100), 
@TENDN nvarchar(100), @MK nvarchar(20))
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @C = 
    'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '+@MANV+'
     WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512
     ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '+@MK+''

EXEC(@C)

INSERT INTO NHANVIEN (MANV, HOTEN, EMAIL, LUONG, TENDN, MATKHAU, PUBKEY) 
VALUES (@MANV, @HOTEN, @EMAIL, ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(@MANV),@LUONGCB), @TENDN, HASHBYTES('SHA1', @MK), @MANV)

END;
```

When I use this stored procedure, the value of LUONG is NULL. What's the problem?

It doesn't create RSA in file ASYMMETRIC KEYS, which means CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEYS doesnt work. Why?

Comment: My input is 'EXEC SP_INS_PUBLIC_NHANVIEN '1','2','','1000000000','3','4''
|||Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: `......'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '+QUOTENAME(@MANV)+'.....`

Comment: Now it goes Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'RSA_512'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '4'.

Comment: Rsa_512&1024 are deprecated...use another algorithm..

Comment: This's the exercise of my teacher. I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: RSA_1024 and RSA_512 are deprecated. To use RSA_1024 or RSA_512 (not recommended) you must set the database to database compatibility level 120 or lower. ...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-asymmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

Comment: it still goes ERROR Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '4'.
 and value of LUONG still NULL. But Incorrect syntax near 'RSA_512' just been solve

Comment: Print @c before/instead of exec() and check what's missing...

Comment: It didn't print anything. Why?

Answer (score 0):

..feel free to improve..

```
--drop asymmetric key [myasymmetrickey];
--go


--key
declare @asymkeyname sysname, @asymkeypassword nvarchar(128);
-- encryptme
declare @encryptme nvarchar(30) /*better make it 26 if nvarchar or 53 if varchar*/;

select @asymkeyname = N'myasymmetrickey', @asymkeypassword = N'123456?';
select @encryptme = N'encrypt:53byte=max26nchars'; --rsa_512 can encrypt max 53bytes..if datalength(string) > 53 then encrypresult=null

begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(500);

    if nullif(@asymkeyname, '') is null 
    begin
        raiserror('no key name!', 16, 1);
        return; -- -1
    end


    if asymkey_id(@asymkeyname) is null 
    begin 

        if len(isnull(@asymkeypassword, N'') < 6)
        begin
            raiserror('password too short!', 16, 1);
            return; -- -1
        end
        
        begin try
            select @sql = N'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '+QUOTENAME(@asymkeyname)+N' WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512 ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + replace(@asymkeypassword, '''', '''''') + N'''';
            exec (@sql)
        end try
        begin catch
            select error_message() as error;
            return -- -1
        end catch
    end

    select 
        encryptbyasymkey(asymkey_id(@asymkeyname),@encryptme) as binaryencrypted, 
        hashbytes('SHA1', @asymkeypassword) as asymkeypasswordhashed;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE Proc sp_Ins_Public_NHANVIEN (
            @manv    sysname,       @hoten nvarchar(100), @email varchar(20),
            @luongcb nvarchar(100), @tendn nvarchar(100), @mk   nvarchar(20)) as
begin
    declare @c nvarchar(MAX)

    if Asymkey_Id(@manv) is null
    begin
        set @c = 'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '    + quoteName(@manv) + ' ' +
                 'WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512 ' + 
                 'ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ' + quoteName(@mk , nchar(39))
        exec (@c)
    end

    insert into NHANVIEN (MANV, HOTEN, EMAIL, LUONG, TENDN, MATKHAU, PUBKEY)
    values (@manv, @hoten, @email,
            EncryptByAsymKey(Asymkey_Id(@manv), @luongcb),
            @tendn, hashBytes('SHA1', @mk), 
            (select convert(nvarchar(256), public_key, 2)
               from sys.asymmetric_keys where name = @manv)
            )
end
```